# Smart way to determine a limit

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I'm looking for a way to improve the following statement:

```
var limit = images.length > 15 ? 15 : images.length;
```

I know about the `||` operator but I cannot seem to find a good way of using it here.
Is there any way to improve this statement?

Comment: I see only one slight improvement. `var totalImages = images.length;
var limit = totalImages > 15 ? 15 : totalImages;`

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific. How kind of improvement do you want? Performance? Aesthetics? What's your use case anyway? What do you do with that `limit`? Maybe `.slice()` would be a good option.

Comment: Just a smarter way. 2 times "15" and 2 times "images.length" just seemed so inconvenient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `min`.

```
var limit = Math.min(images.length, 15);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can logically stretch it only this far -

```
var limit = (images.length > 15 ? 15 : images.length) || 0;
```